# Merge subarray and get random values from result array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a string permutation for an array of values or for a single string and this is how I am doing:

```
function aliasName($string)
{
    $names = [];

    if (is_array($string)) {
        foreach ($string as $str) {
            $names[] = internalProcessing($str);
        }
    } else {
        $names[] = internalProcessing($string);
    }

    return $names[array_rand($names)];
}

function internalProcessing($str)
{
    $names = [];

    $input = strtolower($str);
    $length = strlen($input);
    $counter = pow(2, $length);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; ++$i) {
        $binaryStr = str_pad(decbin($i), $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $variant = '';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $length; ++$j) {
            $variant .= ($binaryStr[$j] == '1') ? strtoupper($input[$j]) : $input[$j];
        }

        $names[] = $variant;
    }

    return $names;
}

$test1 = ['Mami', 'Abonis', 'Acierto', 'Alison', 'Bato', 'Chiste', 'Amada', 'Calor', 'Dato', 'Fiera', 'Exito'];
$test2 = 'mamI';

$test1Result = aliasName($test1);
$test2Result = aliasName($test2);

echo "\n test1 -------------------------------- \n";
var_export($test1Result);
echo "\n test2 -------------------------------- \n";
var_export($test2Result);
```

The code works good but I have a few issues and I need some help. If you run the code above in a console script you should see an output like the one below:

```
# php test.php

 test1 --------------------------------
array (
  0 => 'abonis',
  1 => 'aboniS',
  2 => 'abonIs',
  3 => 'abonIS',
  4 => 'aboNis',
  5 => 'aboNiS',
  6 => 'aboNIs',
  7 => 'aboNIS',
  8 => 'abOnis',
  9 => 'abOniS',
  10 => 'abOnIs',
  ...
)

 test2 --------------------------------
array (
  0 => 'mami',
  1 => 'mamI',
  2 => 'maMi',
  3 => 'maMI',
  4 => 'mAmi',
  5 => 'mAmI',
  6 => 'mAMi',
  7 => 'mAMI',
  8 => 'Mami',
  9 => 'MamI',
  10 => 'MaMi',
  ...
)
```

`test2` output is just fine, but `test1` is not. If you dump the content of `$names` at `internalProcessing()` (just before the return) you'll get something like:

```
// var_export($names);  
// return $names;

# php test.php
array (
  0 => 'mami',
  1 => 'mamI',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'abonis',
  1 => 'aboniS',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'acierto',
  1 => 'aciertO',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'alison',
  1 => 'alisoN',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'bato',
  1 => 'batO',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'chiste',
  1 => 'chistE',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'amada',
  1 => 'amadA',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'calor',
  1 => 'caloR',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'dato',
  1 => 'datO',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'fiera',
  1 => 'fierA',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'exito',
  1 => 'exitO',
  ...
)array (
  0 => 'mami',
  1 => 'mamI',
  ...
)
```

I need to transform that output to something like:

```
$result_array = array (
    0 => 'mami',
    1 => 'mamI',
    ...,
    0 => 'abonis',
    1 => 'aboniS',
    ...,
    0 => 'acierto',
    1 => 'aciertO',
    ...,
    0 => 'alison',
    1 => 'alisoN',
    ...,
    0 => 'bato',
    1 => 'batO',
    ...,
    0 => 'chiste',
    1 => 'chistE',
    ...,
    0 => 'amada',
    1 => 'amadA',
    ...,
    0 => 'calor',
    1 => 'caloR',
    ...,
    0 => 'dato',
    1 => 'datO',
    ...,
    0 => 'fiera',
    1 => 'fierA',
    ...,
    0 => 'exito',
    1 => 'exitO',
    ...,
    0 => 'mami',
    1 => 'mamI',
    ...
  )
```

And finally if the input is an array of values then I should return any random values between 0 and count($result_array). I have tried `array_merge()` but didn't works for me since I got wrong result. Can any give me some push here?

Comment: What is wrong with output of test1, that is not wrong in test2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed arrays of arrays, as *internalProcessing* returns an array, and you put that result as an array element in a wrapping array with this:

```
 $names[] = internalProcessing(...);
```

Instead you should store the result of *internalProcessing* as follows (in both occurrences):

```
 $names = array_merge($names, internalProcessing(...));
```

That does the trick as you can see in this [fiddle](https://eval.in/513318).

Comment: Didn't work for me, I am getting the same output array of arrays,  did you tried?

Comment: nvm, since the first result is a multi-dimensional array then I've changed from `array_merge` to `array_merge_recursive` and that does the job. Thank for the heads up!

Comment: With the example you had given there is no need for  `array_merge_recursive` (I added a fiddle), but I am glad it works out for you.